# Node.js server stopping when unzipping a .rar file

Tags: node.js, unzip

I am using `unzip` module in Node.js for extracting archives.

`unzip` is working fine for `.zip` files but when I try to extract `.rar` files, the server is stopping unexpectedly.

```
fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: folder }));
```

error:

```
Error: invalid signature: 0x5c3a4322
    at PATH_TO_MYPROJECT\node_modules\unzip\lib\parse.js:63:13
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

The problem still persists even I put the whole code in a `try/catch` block.

```
try {
    fs.createReadStream(filepath).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: folder }));
} catch(e) {
    //do something here...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zip and Rar are two differents file formats.

The library `unzip` only works with `zip` files, not with `rar` ones. You will need another library like [tar](https://github.com/isaacs/node-tar).